# How to make web page print friendly using php code?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a plain dynamic webpage having a report data with unformulated way. I Want to generate a report style data so I want only functionality in printing stage.

Can any one tell me How can I do it?

I tried some of code in  my page

```
<?php
if($mode == 'print') $stylesheet = 'tp.css';
    else $stylesheet = 'style.css';
echo '<link rel="Stylesheet" href="'.$stylesheet.'" type="text/css" />';
?>

<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?mode=print'; ?>">Printer friendly version</a>
```

try to change a style sheet but having different problem.

I acutely required to print my web site page for visitor on [McaGurus.com](http://www.McaGurus.com)

thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just add stylesheets in your HTML. Adding the `media` attribute to use it for screen or print.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the normal method to include stylesheets in your page but add the `media` attribute to define what purpose it has.

```
<link href='screen.css' rel='stylesheet' media="screen" type='text/css'>
```

is used to display your page on screen.

```
<link href='print.css' rel='stylesheet' media="print" type='text/css'>
```

is used for your print.

Answer (score 1):

Just use media="print" on include link for print styles, it will use those styles only on priting stage.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css"/>
```